# SSE operator+= for vectors

Tags: c, performance, vector, sse

I have two arrays of `double` type and I want to perform `vecA += vecB`. So far, I am doing `vecA = vecA + vecB` and as far as I know, for e.g. integers writing `i = i + 5` is slower than `i += 5`. So I am wondering, whether there is some SSE function to do just an `operator+=` on __m128d. I searched and found nothing. My application spends approx 60% of time on this `vecA = vecA + vecB` operation , so any performance gains will show.

All arrays in the code snippets below are 16-bytes aligned and `len` is always even.

The original code is simply

```
inline void addToDoubleVectorSSE(
         const double * what, const double * toWhat, double * dest, const unsigned int len)
{
   __m128d * _what      = (__m128d*)what;
   __m128d * _toWhat    = (__m128d*)toWhat;

   for ( register unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i+= 2 )
   {
       *_toWhat = _mm_add_pd( *_what, *_toWhat );
       _what++;
       _toWhat++;
   }
}
```

After reading http://fastcpp.blogspot.cz/2011/04/how-to-process-stl-vector-using-sse.html where the author gains performance by not writing immediately into what he just read from, I tried

```
__m128d * _what         = (__m128d*)what;
__m128d * _toWhat       = (__m128d*)toWhat;
__m128d * _toWhatBase   = (__m128d*)toWhat;

__m128d _dest1;
__m128d _dest2;

for ( register unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i+= 4 )
{
    _toWhatBase = _toWhat;
    _dest1      = _mm_add_pd( *_what++, *_toWhat++ );
    _dest2      = _mm_add_pd( *_what++, *_toWhat++ );

    *_toWhatBase++ = _dest1;
    *_toWhatBase++ = _dest2;
}
```

but speedwise no improvement happens. So, is there any `operator+=` for `__m128d`? Or is there some other way that I can use to perform operator+= on arrays of doubles? The target platform is always going to be Windows (XP and 7) on Intel i7 CPUs, using MSVC.

Comment: What makes you say `i = i + 5` is slower than `i += 5`?

Comment: I don't think it is related to c language.
if you need some speedup, good idea would be to check the assembly code generated from your sources...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no equivalent of `+=`, because SSE arithmetic operations are generally register-to-register or memory-to-register, but not register-to-memory.

However, you can improve on your performance using the advise from the blog post that you linked. The reason the trick failed to work for you is that you did not eliminate the dependency between the two instructions: the side effects of the `++` increment in `_what++` and `_toWhat++` prevent the second pair of operations from starting at the same time. Modify your loop as follows to get an improvement:

```
for ( register unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i+= 4, _what += 2, _toWhat += 2, _toWhatBase+=2 )
{
    _toWhatBase = _toWhat;
    _dest1      = _mm_add_pd( *_what, *_toWhat );
    _dest2      = _mm_add_pd( *(_what+1), *(_toWhat+1));

    *_toWhatBase = _dest1;
    *(_toWhatBase+1) = _dest2;
}
```

After the change, the operation on `_dest2` becomes independent of the operation on `_dest1`

According to my wall clock estimates, I got about 28% improvement after this simple modification.

Comment: Thank you. I tried (copy pasted your code), but runtime decreased from 36.14s to 36.13s only. Could the improvement be complier dependent? Or is there a compiler switch that enables performing operations on `_dest1` and `_dest2` "paralelly"?

Comment: @DanBencik I don't know if this is a compiler dependent or a CPU dependent. Here is my benchmark code [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/LAzm5HAS). I am using VS2010. When I run it as is, clock count that gets printed is 2968; when I comment out lines 34..42, and uncomment lines 44..52 to get back to your code, the clock count I get is 4170.

Comment: When I run your benchmark, I get results similar to yours so I have no idea why in the whole application the benefits to your implementation don't show. I will take a look in the evening when I have a profiler available and will report back. Thanks!

Comment: I got some results. My code is available [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Z1pQ6Sdp) as well, thanks for the site. The only change in my code is that I am not always summing the same two arrays but I change the arrays to sum. I allocate 1000 arrays into a, b, c and them sum c[i] = a[i] + b[i]. Now the difference between FAST_SSE and SSE is  16281 clocks vs 16437 clocks. Is the memory->cache transfer responsible for speed indifference?

Comment: @DanBencik I see the same results with your code: `FAST_SSE` makes very little difference. I think the reason is that since you are adding different numbers all the time, cache to memory speed becomes the critical bottleneck. If this is the case, vectorizing is not going to help much: in fact, SSE over the "plain" `+=` should not make that much of a difference if it's the memory that's slowing you down.

Comment: Can I measure whether the results are caused by this? For example, is this going to show in a larger count in cache misses? Many thanks for the discussion!

Comment: @DanBencik Yes, I expect a high number of cache misses to happen when you increase the size of your arrays, and use more different arrays (like you did in the modified benchmark test).

Answer (score 4):

You are doing unnecessary work, modern compilers automatically generate this kind of code.  The feature is called "auto-vectorization".  MSVC supports it as well in VS2012.  I couldn't make much sense of your code so I rewrote it like this:

```
inline void addToDoubleVectorSSE(
         const double * what, double * toWhat, const unsigned int len)
{
    for (unsigned ix = 0; ix < len; ++ix) 
        toWhat[ix] += what[ix];
}
```

Which produced this machine code:

```
00A3102E  xor         eax,eax  
00A31030  movupd      xmm0,xmmword ptr [esp+eax+358h]  
00A31039  movupd      xmm1,xmmword ptr [esp+eax+38h]  
00A3103F  add         eax,10h  
00A31042  addpd       xmm1,xmm0                          // <=== Look!!
00A31046  movupd      xmmword ptr [esp+eax+348h],xmm1  
00A3104F  cmp         eax,320h  
00A31054  jb          wmain+30h (0A31030h)
```

Clearly you should favor this solution given how much cleaner the code looks.  Update your VS version if necessary.

Comment: Hans, thanks for this point. The difference in runtime is 39.47s (nonSSE) versus 36.14s (SSE) so it's not as a big deal as I thought.